# Where does Moxtra store data?

Tags: ios

I am planning to use moxtra in my iOS healthcare app.but concern about security.
Where does moxtra store data? is this data store in encrypted form?
Can we use our server(AWS) to store data?

Answer (score 0):

http://moxtra.com/embeddables/security/

Moxtra security white paper: http://moxtra.com/resources/?category_name=whitepaper

Comment: Thank You raj, We are developing app for US based healthcare and looking forward to use moxtra, but we have some question, like how can we retrieved required data from AWS (can we store data in our AWS) and lot more..how i can get in touch with moxtra team, i have mailed them and try to chat but no reply from them

Comment: Please write to us at support@moxtra.com . We will get in touch with you promptly. Thanks.